# jquery ui sortable is making copies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm rather new to javascript and especially jQuery UI. I'm trying make a (what I thought easy) "drag and drop" area where the drop-section also needs to be sortable. The dragging and dropping is working, but the sorting is only working for about 20%... The problem is when I sort an element, it's leaving a copy and a clone, instead of just moving it.

I think this has to do with me setting the helper in the draggable section to making a clone in the droppable area and the cloning part is still doing it's job when I'm trying to sort the elements. I hope I'm being clear in my description...

See code below. The 2 's are the elements I want to drop and then sort.

```
<div id="draggable1">
     <H1>Headline</H1>
</div>
<div id="draggable2">
     <input type="text" value="move me..." class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="droppable"></div>

$("#draggable1, #draggable2").draggable({
     helper: 'clone',
     cursor: 'move'
});

$("#droppable").sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
     cursor: 'move',
     helper: 'copy'
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
     drop: function (event, ui) {
         var droppable = $(this);
         var draggable = ui.draggable;
         draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
     }
});
```

After I sort, there is both a copy and a clone. See image.

[image: This is what it looks like with drag and drop functionality...]

[image: This is after I sort the Headline element 1 step down.]

[Here link to fiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/xLk8b1w3) for you guys too see my code and what happens.

I get the same result there...

Comment: Remove `helper: 'clone'` and `helper: 'copy'`. If that doesn't solve your problem, then we need to see a working example of it, either here in a snippet or on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I added the 'copy' to see if it would override the 'clone'. I need the 'clone' since I want the elements to stay in the left section. I f I remove 'clone' it will move the entire element...

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you guys.. I get the same result there...

https://jsfiddle.net/xLk8b1w3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#draggable1").draggable();
  $("#draggable2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("h1").css("fontSize", "18px");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $("h1").css("fontSize", "30px");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Also include jQueryUI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable1">
  <H1>Headline</H1>
</div>
<div id="draggable2">
  <input type="text" value="move me..." class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="droppable"></div>
```

Comment: i think this helps you

Comment: Hi, sorry but I don't get the solution? My code is posted as a fiddle now, pls check.